# Why do I get duplicate results and how do I avoid it?

Tags: python, sql

I have written some code that looks inside all .sql Files in a given path (and its subfolders) for table names saved in the variable table_list.

The code looks like this:

```
import os
import fnmatch

table_list = ['TABLE1', 'TABLE2', 'TABLE3', blabla]
    
  
    root_dir = "mypath\\blabla"
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(root_dir):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.sql'):
            file_path = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
            with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
                for line in f:
                    for table in table_list:
                        if table.upper() in line:
                             print(file_path)
                             print(table)
```

Now my output kinda looks like this. How do I get rid of the duplicates (Path + Table combination)?

```
Path1
Table1
Path1
Table1
Path1
Table1
Path1
Table2
Path1
Table2
```

etc...

Comment: Don't `print` the info right away. Instead, put it in a `set` and the print the `set` after processing the entire file.

Comment: Also that `os.walk` + `filtering` sounds like you need [`pathlib.Path.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob).